# Group by UNION result

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have 2 tables: 'parent' and 'child'

CHILD:

```
ID  |   NAME        | PARENT_ID
--------------------------------
1   |   Child 1     |   1
2   |   Child 2     |   1
3   |   Child 3     |   1
4   |   Child 4     |   1
5   |   Child 5     |   1
6   |   Child 6     |   2
7   |   Child 7     |   2
8   |   Child 8     |   2
9   |   Child 9     |   2
10  |   Child 10    |   2
11  |   Child 11    |   2
12  |   Child 12    |   2
13  |   Child 13    |   2
14  |   Child 14    |   2
15  |   Child 15    |   3
16  |   Child 16    |   3
17  |   Child 17    |   3
```

PARENT:

```
ID  |   NAME        |   UNIQUE_ID
----------------------------------
1   |   PARENT 1    |   uniq-001
2   |   PARENT 2    |   uniq-002
3   |   PARENT 3    |   uniq-003
```

i want to union this two table and get result like this

```
ID  |   NAME        |   PARENT_ID
---------------------------------
1   |   parent 1    |   1
1   |   child 1     |   1
2   |   child 2     |   1
2   |   parent 2    |   2
6   |   child 6     |   2
7   |   child 7     |   2
12  |   child 12    |   2
13  |   child 13    |   2
14  |   child 14    |   2
3   |   parent 3    |   3
15  |   child 15    |   3
```

my sql code looks like

```
select * from 
(
SELECT 
    id, 
    name,
    id as parent_id
from 
    parent
UNION all
SELECT 
    id, 
    name,
    parent_id
from 
    child
) t
group by 3, 1, 2
```

i dont know why, but the result is not grouped by PARENT_ID.
How can i group this query by PARENT_ID?

Comment: Does it work if you specify the columns explicitly? (`group by parent_id, id, name`)

Comment: Do you just want an `order by`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i want to after each parent display his childs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the question is not clear enough.
Here are two suggestions for start.

Dudu

---

```
select      id
           ,name
           ,unique_id

from        (           select 2,id,parent_id,name,null      from child
            union all   select 1,id,id       ,name,unique_id from parent
            ) t (source_order,id,pid,name,unique_id)

order by    pid
           ,source_order
           ,id
;
```

---

```
id      name        unique_id
--      ----        ---------
1       PARENT 1    uniq-001
1       Child 1     
2       Child 2     
3       Child 3     
4       Child 4     
5       Child 5     
2       PARENT 2    uniq-002
6       Child 6     
7       Child 7     
8       Child 8     
9       Child 9     
10      Child 10    
11      Child 11    
12      Child 12    
13      Child 13    
14      Child 14    
3       PARENT 3    uniq-003
15      Child 15    
16      Child 16    
17      Child 17
```

---

```
select      p.*
           ,(select array_agg ('(' || c.id || ') ' || c.name order by c.id) from child as c where c.parent_id = p.id)   as children

from        parent as p

order by    p.id
;
```

---

```
id  name        unique_id   childrn
--  ----        ---------   -------
1   PARENT 1    uniq-001    (1) Child 1 ,(2) Child 2 ,(3) Child 3 ,(4) Child 4 ,(5) Child 5 
2   PARENT 2    uniq-002    (6) Child 6 ,(7) Child 7 ,(8) Child 8 ,(9) Child 9 ,(10) Child 10,(11) Child 11,(12) Child 12,(13) Child 13,(14) Child 14
3   PARENT 3    uniq-003    (15) Child 15,(16) Child 16,(17) Child 17
```